# Export Data from Sql Server to To Excel Using Sqlbulkcopy

Tags: sql-server, excel, sqlbulkcopy

is any one here have the idea to export/copy data from sql server to excel.

I use `OPENROWSET` and its working but the client wants to get the data using bulk copy
is there a way to get the data using the `Sqlbulkcopy`

and I use also `ErickEJ's` sqlcebulkcopy to try this out but it only uses compact database.

Comment: `SqlBulkCopy` is for importing data ***into** SQL Server, not for exporting it. To export it just use SSIS. (Additionally, SQL Server's `BULK` features tend to require a very-specific data format on-disk, it is not suitable for Excel or CSV interop (namely because it doesn't even support Excel's own weird CSV formatting rules, let alone backslash escape sequences seen in other CSV formats, _le sigh_).

Comment: oh I see I think my sentence is a little bit  complicated I forgot to add "Is sqlbulkcopy can be use to export data from Sql server to Excel". Ok I think I try to use and suggest it to my client to have SSIS or Openrowset to be use to their exporting of data.

Comment: `sqlbulkcopy` is a C# class. So if you're going to use C#, why not use a class that lets you export data?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid. Hi thanks for suggesting that, I already did exporting data using 'Microsoft.Office.Interop' while using For Loop to loop through the records, but it is time consuming even if that data takes records once in a month, records have 300k plus  and counting so using Loop is not a good idea, by the way I using SSIS now and its more better